# Using AWSS3TransferManager to upload a file to S3 is incredibly slow

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, awss3transfermanager

For whatever reason when I try to upload a file to S3 using AWSS3TransferManager it is incredibly slow, both in the iOS simulator and on device (iPhone and iPad). I'm on a 1Gbps fiber connection, so that shouldn't be it, and I'm experiencing the same speeds on LTE.

Starting out at about 200KB/s and then it slows to a crawl at around 10-20KB/s.

Any idea what might be causing this? Anybody else have the same issues with AWSS3TransferManager?

Comment: It looks like the client automatically handles multipart uploads but the minimum file size is 5MB. How large are the files you're testing against?

Comment: @DaveMaple they're all 500MB+.

EDIT: Actually some are 20-100MB, but I see the same no matter which size the files are.

Comment: A few things

A) What version of the SDK are you using?
B) Does this happen if it's only a single large file (i.e. Waiting for one to finish before starting the next)
C) Does this happen if you are only uploading a bunch of files under 5MB  or under 20MB?

Comment: @ChristianA.Strømmen Are you able to fix this issue?